# How to combine rows in a df while adding the matrix values

Tags: r, dataframe

Just stuck on some df manipulation. I have a large ASV matrix with samples as rows and taxa as columns. I would like to merge specific rows while adding the matrix values of those rows.

Example data frame (code below):

[image]

I would like to merge sample-1, sample-2, and sample-3 with each other. Same for sample-4 and sample-5. The merged dataset would have only two rows which contain the summation of the values for each previous row. (Specifically the first three rows would become a single row with new ASV values: ASV1=11, ASV2=14, ASV3=1, ASV4=2, ASV5=8).

```
> dput(example.matrix)
structure(list(ASV1 = c(8L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 1L), ASV2 = c(1L, 4L, 
9L, 3L, 2L), ASV3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), ASV4 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
3L, 0L), ASV5 = c(0L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("sample-1", 
"sample-2", "sample-3", "sample-4", "sample-5"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(group = c(1,1,1,2,2)) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), sum))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  group  ASV1  ASV2  ASV3  ASV4  ASV5
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    11    14     1     2     8
2     2     7     5     2     3     4
```

Comment: It depends pn which sample groups you want to combine. Os it always sample1,2,3 vs 4 and 5?